# Thread one program received: SIGKILL, only in 4.3 Simulator

Tags: ios, sigkill

When I use the 5.0 simulator I don't get any error at all.

When I use the 4.3 simulator I get the following message when I stop the execution of the app in Xcode using the the stop button.

Basically, I am navigating through my program and I launch a view with a uiwebview the following comes up in the console:

Attaching to process 13343.
[Switching to process 13343 thread 0x2103]

I continue using the App and I only when I stop the execution do I get the following error message:

Thread one program received: SIGKILL

I think the issue is that another thread was opened when it requires user interaction from the uiwebview.  And, then when I send the kill message the first thread receives the sigkill and complains with the error.

If I load the same view without the uiwebview, I don't get the error message at all.

And, when I use the 5.0 simulator I don't get this error message at all when loading the uiwebview.

I have seen similar behaviour with the uitextview.

Is this something I should be worried about?  It doesn't seem to be a problem when running on the actual hardware.

Is there a way I can switch back to thread one after I push the other view and am done with the uiwebview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIGKILL is sent by the OS to any app to tell it to quit what it's running and remove its processes.  SIGKILL is not an error on your part, and is not a simulator bug, it's what happens when you press the home button and kill the app in the multitasking drawer, or press the stop button on Xcode.  So to reiterate, do not think its your fault, it's just the simulator freaking out sometimes.  (Like once, I kept a device in debug mode and restarted my device and got like 300 lines of binary in the log, that was creepy!)

PS (though I HIGHLY doubt you are having this problem: SIGKILL may also be sent in cases where your app is using WAY too much memory, which would cause an exception or an EXC_BAD_ACCESS depending on how you managed to do it, but again, highly unlikely).

Comment: But, why am I only seeing it in the 4.3 simulator and not the 5.0 simulator?  That's why I am concerned, but maybe I shouldn't be.

Comment: You shouldn't be.  Like I said, sometimes the debugger doesn't respond as quickly as it should, so it interprets the SIGKILL as an exception and shows you the offending line of code.  Don't worry, again, it's totally not your fault.  The simulators act weird all the time.